# Unable to retrieve data from my database with spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to save a list of objects that have others objects as attributes using ***save()*** method of ***Spring   CrudRepository***.
My service is as below

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl implements DBDataManipulatorService {

@Autowired
private AircraftRepository aircraftRepository;
@Autowired
private WorkPackageRepository workPackageRepository;
@Autowired
private MyJobRepository myJobRepository;

@Override
@Transactional
public List<MyJob> saveToDataBase(List<MyJob> jobs) {

    List<MyJob> newJobs = new ArrayList<MyJob>();
    MyJob myJob = null;

    for (MyJob job : jobs) {
        myJob = myJobRepository.save(job);
        newJobs.add(myJob);
    }

    return newJobs;
} ...
```

and myJob class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="job", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"jobId"}))
public class MyJob implements Serializable {


@Id
@Column(name = "jobId")
private String jobId;
    private String jobStatus;

    @ManyToOne()
private Aircraft aircraft;

@ManyToOne()
private WorkPackage workPackage;
....
```

And Aircraft class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aircraft", uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"aircraftId"}))
public class Aircraft implements Serializable{


@Id
@Column(name = "aircraftId")
private String aircraftId;

@Column (name = "TYPE")
private String type;

@Column (name = "MODEL")
private String model;
```

And when I execute the following test :

```
@Test
public void testSaveToDataBaseWithFiles() {

HTMLDataExtractorServiceImpl htmlDataExtractorService = new    HTMLDataExtractorServiceImpl();
    Map<String, MyJob> jobsMap = htmlDataExtractorService.parsePage("/Report.html");
    List<MyJob> jobs = new ArrayList<MyJob>(jobsMap.values());

    List<MyJob> myjobs =  dbDataManipulatorService.saveToDataBase(jobs);

    jobsMap = myJobsListToMyJobsMap(myjobs);

    MyJob myJob = jobsMap.get("20316408");

    assertEquals("SUCCESS",myJob.getJobStatus());
    assertEquals("50005", myJob.getAircraft().getAircraftId());
    assertEquals("WP6_27", myJob.getWorkPackage().getWorkPackageId());

}
```

I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.domain.Aircraft with id 50004; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.domain.Aircraft with id 50004
```

I understand that there is a problem with the save method, but I don't know how to solve it.  Can anyone help, please?

Comment: And where exactly is this exception being thrown. What class and line?

Comment: it is thrown in ***testSaveToDataBaseWithFiles*** and in the line     `jobsMap = myJobsListToMyJobsMap(myjobs);`

Comment: The exception has bubbled up the stack so the problem lies deeper in your code. Can you show us the `myJobsListToMyJobsMap` or more?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to guess, since we don't know what you get from the

```
Map<String, MyJob> jobsMap = htmlDataExtractorService.parsePage("/Report.html");
```

but my guess would be the missing cascading configuration. Your jobsMap seems to contain a MyJob object associated with an Aircraft of id 5004, however this Aircraft seems not to be persisted previously. If you mark the association with

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

or

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
```

JPA should persist the Aircraft automatically for you.